# how to use regex in logstash for url link

Tags: logstash

I am using the logstash to load data to elsatic search . 
I'm facing an issue with below condition

```
if [field] =~ '/t.co/'
```

getting an error  unknown regexp option , Please help me get it rid of this issue

```
field value having '/t.co/somevalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use single quotation marks, as I understand you want to filter all fields that start with `t.co` with a dot inside? Then you should try this:

```
if [field] =~ /t\.co.*/
```